# Type error when using knex promises and pg in node

Tags: node.js, database, knex.js, pg

I am trying to connect my postgresql database using knex and pg npm module.
If i do `console.log(db.select('*').table('users'))` then it works well and good but when i use promise like

```
db.select('*').table('users').then(result => {
    console.log(result);
})
```

then it returns type error.

Full code ->

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const cors = require('cors');
const knex = require('knex');

const db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        host: 'localhost',
        database: 'smart-brain'
    }
});

db.select('*').table('users').then(result => {
    console.log(result);
})
```

returns ->

```
internal/crypto/hash.js:88
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('key',
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be one of type string, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type object    at new Hmac (internal/crypto/hash.js:88:11)
    at Object.createHmac (crypto.js:133:10)
    at createHMAC (E:\Web Development\React\Smart Brain Project\smart-brain-api\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:133:17)
    at Hi (E:\Web Development\React\Smart Brain Project\smart-brain-api\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:137:13)
    at Object.continueSession (E:\Web Development\React\Smart Brain Project\smart-brain-api\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:32:24)    at Client._handleAuthSASLContinue (E:\Web Development\React\Smart Brain Project\smart-brain-api\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:248:10)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at parse (E:\Web Development\React\Smart Brain Project\smart-brain-api\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:109:12)
    at Parser.parse (E:\Web Development\React\Smart Brain Project\smart-brain-api\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:40:17)
    at Socket.stream.on (E:\Web Development\React\Smart Brain Project\smart-brain-api\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:8:42)
```

Comment: `console.log(db.select('*').table('users'))` probably "works" because the promise is created but doesnt have time to finish. The program exits before solving (or failing)

Comment: @Rashomon what must be solution then?

Comment: The error comes from `crypto` package. If this is your full code, try removing the import since the package is deprecated

Comment: No its not my full code :(

Comment: Try to update pg driver.